# an issue with compatibility: old jboss/hibernate vs Oracle 12c

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jboss, oracle12c

i'm Oracle-DBA trying to upgrade our Oracle-11g databases onto Oracle-12c. Our web-developers tell me, there is a big problem to work our old applications (a lot of them were developed with old JBOSS 4.2.2 and old Hibernate 3.4.0/3.1.0) to the new the Oracle-database(12c)

Our developers send me this information:

### **Application:

seam-version -> 2.2.2.Final

hibernate-annotations-version -> 3.4.0.GA

hibernate-validator-version -> 3.1.0.GA

jsf-facelets-version -> 1.1.14

rich-faces-version -> 3.3.3.Final

als Dependency:  hibernate-core version 3.3.0.SP1 for Compilieren.

OracleDialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

### JBOSS 4.2.2.GA

Hibernate-Version: 3.2.4.sp1

Hibernate Annotations Version: 3.2.1.GA

Hibernate EntityManager Version: 3.2.1.GA

Oracle JDBC Driver for 11g - ojdbc14

Oracle JDBC Driver for 12c - ojdbc6

so, if you call a PROCEDURE XXXXXXXXX (o_res out sys_refcursor, p_yyyyy IN NUMBER, .... )
it throws this problem:

**....
INFO   |  Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Problem while trying to load or access OracleTypes.CURSOR value
.....................
INFO   |  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect can not access a member of class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes with modifiers ""
Bug: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3159**

although, according this link we should had get a problem even with Oracle-11g, not while trying to upgrade to 12c! ( "With Oracle 11g, the deprecated package oracle.jdbc.driver no longer exists and this causes issues with all OracleDialect classes making it impossible to use Hibernate."(с) )

here one can read: 
**"Try to use org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect, seems to be the highest possible version in Hibernate 4.3.9.
A dialect for 12c seems to be present in later versions, see this."**
(we have even an older version of Hibernate - 3.2.4 ! )

a newer Hibernate (> 3.2.4 ), if i've got it right, is not compatibe with the old Jboss 4.2.2. (is it?! Please disagree with me (=with my colleagues) if you can)

what could be a right decision or workaround to make the 12c-Oracle-upgrade?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: And the reason why your colleagues don't want to update the version of Hibernate/JBoss is ????  Honestly, Java developers frequently complain  about the non-Agile monolithic database.  So what's up with their middle-tier agility?